# Remove End Of File(EOF) in a File

Tags: linux, bash, unix

In UNIX like operating system Is there any way to remove the End of File(EOF) property from files? If it is possible how to remove it?

Comment: Are you sure you know what an EOF *is*? Are you saying you want to create a file of infinite size?

Answer (score 1):

In UNIX end of file is detected when you try to read past the last character in the file. If the current position of your open to read file equals or is greater than the length, then the system returns you the end-of-file condition.